# How to upload a LARGE file by using box-ios-sdk?

Tags: ios, box-api

everybody. I'm using `BoxUploadOperation` interface of `box-ios-sdk` to upload file on iOS platform. I initialized `BoxUploadOperation` instance by using below class method.

```
+ (BoxUploadOperation *)operationForUser:(BoxUser*)user
            targetFolderId:(NSString*)folderId
                data:(NSData *)data
                fileName:(NSString *)fileName
                contentType:(NSString *)contentType
                shouldShare:(BOOL)shouldShare
                message:(NSString *)message
                emails:(NSArray *)emails;
```

The third parameter of this class method need be an `NSData` object, that's good idea for small size file, it's no problem for loading whole file into memory (`NSData`), but that's not good idea for loading a large file into memory, iOS device memory is so limited.

So how can i upload a large file to box.net? 
I have no idea, if someone has suggestion then i appreciates.